# iTunes Connect complains "missing localized screenshot" despite iPhone 5 screenshots being already uploaded

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

My project has bundled a `Default-586h@2x.png` because without it iTunes Connect would complain about "Invalid Binary - not optimized for iPhone 5".

Now the binary still does not appear to be accepted, with error "Missing Localized Screenshot (Australian English)"

But I have already submitted both "3.5 inch retina" and "4.0 inch retina" screenshots.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

In this case, iTunes Connect isn't quite good at explaining the error.

The error is caused by missing iPad screenshot.

When you submit an application profile, iTunes Connect does not tell you that iPad screenshot is mandatory. However, if you continue to upload the application archive, iTunes Connect will come back and tell you there is a "missing screenshot".

Comment: True, same thing happened with me....but this helped me to solve the error.

Comment: *In this case, iTunes Connect isn't quite good at explaining the error.*

iTunes Connect is not good in anything.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have no intention of supporting iPAD in your app. So go to your Xcode app's App Summary tab and select "devices = iPhone". Re-archive and upload your binary again and it will work.

Login to itunesconnect, select your app and choose "Choose Another Language" drop down select Australian English and make sure there are at least one screenshot each for iphone 4 and iphone 5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it wouldn't work even when I put in screenshots that were the right size.

Turns out it worked with PNG files and not JPEG files. Once I saved my screenshots as .png they were accepted and worked great.